# How to change the VPN icon on menu bar in OS X?

Tags: macos, vpn

The change in status for the default VPN icon on the menu bar is very subtle. I think it's just whether the bars are solid grey (not connected) or translucent (connected). I can't tell whether I am connected unless I look at it on purpose, and some wallpaper makes it worse. Is there a way I can customize how they look? (I could check "show time connected" option and that would work, but space on my menu bar is very tight as is. I can't use more space on that.)

Or, are there other VPN indicators that I can put on the menu bar? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are four .pdf icons in the VPN.menu bundle that you can probably change:

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/VPN.menu/Contents/Resources
```

Comment: awesome, thanks! I have some problem getting it to display anything other than greyscale color though, but I guess I can change it to a very the shape.