# Change color / look of AirPort menubar icon in Mac OS X Lion

Tags: osx-lion, airport

How can I change the color / look of the AirPort menubar icon in Mac OS X Lion (10.7.4)?

I've looked around quite thoroughly for these. It appears that they *used* to be in (but are not on my system, 10.7.4):

> /System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/Airport.menu/Contents/Resources/*.someimageformat

As in the VPN images here:
[How to change the VPN icon on menu bar in OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/264194/how-to-change-the-vpn-icon-on-menu-bar-in-os-x)
which I may change later, but I don't use very often so not as important.

- I have found some references on the Internet but they all predate Lion.
- I have searched inside System Preferences.app, AirPort Utility.app,
- I have searched inside all (supposedly) relevant apps/bundles in the CoreServices folder.
- I have found a number of similar 'airport fan' files by searching in `/System/Library/` in various other folders/frameworks, but they are NOT the black/white/gray Menu Bar .icns/png's/pdf's etc. that other '.menu' files seem to have. Activity Monitor gave no clue, as the one process I found I had already searched through in Finder.

Where are these icons?

Comment: I also remember being able to edit those menu bar icons.  Have you considered asking on [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/)?  Might bump into a few more Apple experts over there.

Comment: @Josh This question is perfectly on-topic here. There's no need to push people around – those kinds of comments are actually considered rude. See here: [Is it okay to inform users to stop promoting Apple.SE when a question is fine to stay here?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2967/is-it-okay-to-inform-users-to-stop-promoting-apple-se-when-a-question-is-fine-to)

Comment: @slhck I totally agree that the question is on-topic here.  My comment wasn't intended to be pushy whatsoever.  I thought is was actually quite polite.  It was merely a suggestion to help the OP actually get an answer to his question.

Comment: ... but I will refrain from mentioning the A-word in the future :)

Comment: @Josh Don't take it personally, I know you were just trying to be helpful. The OP can always request migration if they think their question isn't sufficiently answered :) It's just that sometimes, this will lead to cross posting and a little overhead in terms of moderation. Hope you understand!

Comment: I understand, cheers!

Comment: Thanks for helping me try to figure this out (where to post) guys! I did remember about ask different just after I posted this, and went over there to make sure I felt this was going to be a better place to ask, and after searching through similar topics there, I felt this belongs more to SU based on empirical evidence (i.e. similar to the VPN icon topic I link to in my question). Also changes people are asking about on A.SE are more 'topical' (as in scratching the surface), even RE:icons. Josh, I appreciate the reminder! Thanks slhck, AND for nicely formatting my post! I will follow suit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Lion, they're in here:

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreWLANKit.framework/Resources/
```

Comment: BRILLIANT! It didn't come up because _PDF files don't come up as "images"_ in Finder searches! Very strange, b/c Apple considers them images in Aperture searches of the system for 'images' (iPhoto too?). I almost followed that lead of the "Airport.icns" in that folder in my search but checked in one of the other frameworks (with no pdfs, so no clue about this filetype omission in the search)! Wow, I was so close... **thanks so much for the solid info!** Spiff ! Nice Ava+Name!